Use of "the first to do something"

Einstein was the first to adequately describe relativity.


what about Einstein was the first one to adequately describe relativity?

No, "the first" is idiomatic and is understood to mean"the first [person]". It is not "weird to say".

The picture doesn't contain any circles

Please don't paste images of text.  Take the time to write out text, so it can be searched and read.


Einstein was the first to adequately describe relativity.

First can be a noun.  It has this definition and several examples here:

first noun (THING/PERSON) B1 [ S ]
the first person or thing to do or be something, or the first person or thing mentioned:
We've fostered several children. Tina was the first.
My passport was the first to arrive.

The sentence quoted by the OP is fine.
